# Result is not received in Activity which was started with Intent flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, launchmode

I have 3 Activities. `StartupActivity, LoginActivity and PinActivity`.

**StartupActivity starts PinActivity** with `startActivity` and flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`

In StartupActivity I have a REST API call which gets successful and `LoginActivity` is started.

**BackStack**

```
StartupActivity -> PinActivity -> LoginActivity
```

Now **LoginActivity starts PinActivity** for `result` with `startActvityForResult` and flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`

In this case, `PinActivity` was already in the back stack and So it is brought to the front. When a user enters the pin and press `OK button`, I have been setting result using the `setResult` method and finishing `PinActivity`, but no result is received in `LoginActivity` *(**PinActivity** was started from **LoginActivity** with `startActivityForResult`)*.

Comment: post your manifest please.

Comment: all activities are with standard launch mode

Comment: I would need to test this myself, but it is possible that `startActivityForResult()` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` are incompatible. Your navigation seems a bit strange to me. Why are you doing this like this? Please explain.

Comment: PinActivity is started from many activities however sometimes result is expected and sometimes it is not.

Comment: Thats not really what I meant. The question is why you need to use FLAG_REORDER_TO_FRONT. Why should the Activity already be in the stack. It sounds like this should be an Activity that doesn't linger in the stack. But I don't know your application.